# Alphabetical Index in search results

Tags: ios, titanium, searchbar

In iPhone->Contacts->All contacts, the alphabetical index disappears on tapping the search bar.
I would like to know whether anyone has tried to put the index IN the search results of a similar search bar and table view populated with data successfully.And whether there are any restrictions regarding the same in native iOS.

I tried the same in Appcelerator Titanium, and weird results are being displayed. So, I would like to know whether its possible at all, so that i can continue digging.

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely the default `UISearchDisplayController` can't be customized in such a way. You should implement your own custom search display controller if you need this feature that bad.

Comment: I think so too... the searchResultsTableview is a readonly property according to the apple docs.. and no wonder the views are all chaotic. This seems to be the best possible answer at hand. I'll dig through titanium docs and see whether some docs and facts are available. Thanks!